# Azure Media Service returns 0 duration with account filter

Tags: azure, video-streaming, video-processing, azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Service v3 to store and encode videos. As a trial, I'd want to show the initial 30 seconds to the User and they can see the rest if they sign up.
So to get the initial 30 seconds, I decided to use the manifest filter as described in the Azure website.

I created an account filter with the following settings and it got created successfully. However, whenever I try to play that video with the URL, I get the manifest file with duration equals to 0 and video fails to play.

Settings I used:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "presentationTimeRange": {
      "startTimestamp": 0,
      "endTimestamp": 300000000,
      "presentationWindowDuration": 600000000,
      "liveBackoffDuration": 0,
      "timescale": 10000000,
      "forceEndTimestamp": true
    }
  }
}
```

URL I am using to play video:
https://xxx-xxx.streaming.media.azure.net/resource-id/video-name.ism/manifest(filter=free-user)

This is how my original manifest looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<SmoothStreamingMedia TimeScale="10000000" Duration="4317653333" MinorVersion="2" MajorVersion="2">
-<StreamIndex Name="aac_und_2_127999_2_1" Language="und" QualityLevels="1" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(aac_und_2_127999_2_1={start time})" Type="audio" Chunks="72">
<QualityLevel SamplingRate="48000" PacketSize="4" Channels="2" CodecPrivateData="1190" FourCC="AACL" Bitrate="127999" BitsPerSample="16" Index="0" AudioTag="255"/>
<c r="71" d="60160000" t="0"/>
<c d="46293333"/>
</StreamIndex>
-<StreamIndex QualityLevels="5" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})" Type="video" Chunks="72">
<QualityLevel CodecPrivateData="000000016764001FACD9405005BB011000000300100000030320F18319600000000168EBECB22C" FourCC="H264" Bitrate="762429" Index="0" MaxHeight="720" MaxWidth="1280"/>

<QualityLevel CodecPrivateData="000000016764001FACD940F0117EF011000003000100000300320F1831960000000168EBECB22C" FourCC="H264" Bitrate="456443" Index="1" MaxHeight="540" MaxWidth="960"/>

<QualityLevel CodecPrivateData="000000016764001EACD940A02FF97011000003000100000300320F162D960000000168EBECB22C" FourCC="H264" Bitrate="288193" Index="2" MaxHeight="360" MaxWidth="640"/>

<QualityLevel CodecPrivateData="0000000167640015ACD941E08FEB011000000300100000030320F162D9600000000168EBECB22C" FourCC="H264" Bitrate="157781" Index="3" MaxHeight="270" MaxWidth="480"/>

<QualityLevel CodecPrivateData="000000016764000CACD941419F9F011000000300100000030320F14299600000000168EBECB22C" FourCC="H264" Bitrate="99525" Index="4" MaxHeight="180" MaxWidth="320"/>

<c r="71" d="60000000" t="0"/>

<c d="54800000"/>

</StreamIndex>

</SmoothStreamingMedia>
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?
filter

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you actually have timestamp 0 in your manifest? The startTimestamp and endTimestamp settings select the range of actual timestamps in your manifest.

You can open the manifest here:
https://xxx-xxx.streaming.media.azure.net/resource-id/video-name.ism/manifest

Comment: Correct, the timestamps you are using probably do not match the actual Start time of your stream if it is a live recording.   Live encoders usually start at a future timestamp and not at 0.

Comment: I have added my original manifest to the question. Could you have a look and share if anything is wrong with it? MIne is not a live stream but recorded videos.